# Spring boot JPA does not persist changes in single test scope

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.1 with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

In database I have 3 records. I perform such test:

```
@Test
public void shouldDeleteByName() {
    service.deleteOneByName("SOME NAME"); // Out of 3 records 1 was deleted
    List<Customer> customers = service.selectAll();
    assertThat(customers).hasSize(2); // FAILS
assertThat(customers).extracting("name").doesNotContain("SOME NAME"); // FAILS
}
```

There are no errors, I see that transaction is committed.

It seems that transaction either gets reverted before `selectAll` or `selectAll` doesn't see changes yet.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: what does service.selectAll() return before you call the delete?

Comment: List with 3 customers entities.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems it solved my issue:

1. I changed my test DB configuration transactionManager to `JpaTransactionManager` from `DataSourceTransactionManager`, example posted at the end.
2. I annotated my service as @Transactional.
3. I annotated my test as @Transactional (without this works, but changes are permanent). Test executes first time, but fails second time.

Code for first step **WORKING ONE**:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```